# Change year format to a specific format

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have this date data in my excel file:

```
18-09-14

18-09-17

18-09-18
```

My problem is how can I make the year format into `4-digit` format, like this:

```
2018-09-14

2018-09-17

2018-09-18
```

I tried `.to_datetime` and `.strftime` of pandas but it throws me an error. Is there any other way to solve this? Any idea, thank you so much!

Comment: Is the origin data a string looks like a date, or a date formatted as "yy-mm-dd"?

Comment: @newacc2240 yah, the original data was formatted as "yy-mm-dd".

Comment: 18-mm-dd is not a valid format because the year must be yyyy so if you have these values in excel its better convert using excel in the yyyy-mm-dd format and than use.

Comment: @Sigma so there's no other way to solve my problem? I have to manually edit it using excel?

Comment: What is the error message and your code?

Comment: `pd.to_datetime('18-09-14', format="%y-%m-%d")` should work. Add the format correctly.

Comment: @N.Omugs a solution is to use join to add to each date at the begining the 20 to get 2018 but this is valid just for 2000 year and now

Comment: If your date data is only post  the year `2000`. Try string concatenation like `df[col] = 20+df.ix[:,col]`

Comment: @PankajJoshi `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'strftime'`, it throws with that error, I put the column in a dataframe then store it in an array. Then after that i use `.strftime` to the array where my dataframe was stored.

Comment: @PankajJoshi i think your code is good but how can i make more flexible that it can read all the column in my excel with that date data? . I tried to store all the date data in an array like this `pd.to_datetime(df1, format="%y-%m-%d")` but it throws me an error (`ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [day,month,year] is missing`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, convert the string to `datetime` datatype using [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and parameter `yearfirst=True` then use [`strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) as:

```
pd.to_datetime('18-09-14',yearfirst=True).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
'2018-09-14'
```

Or if it is a dataframe then:

```
pd.to_datetime(df[0],yearfirst=True).dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
0    2018-09-14
1    2018-09-17
2    2018-09-18
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Comment: `df1 = pd.read_excel('Employee Timesheet.xlsx')
df2 = df1.iloc[:,2]
df3 = pd.DataFrame(df2)
df4 = pd.to_datetime(df3,yearfirst=True).dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
print(df4)` this my code but it throws me an error like this `ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [day,month,year] is missing`

Comment: `df4 = pd.to_datetime(df1.iloc[:,2],yearfirst=True).dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")` , thanks bro! this code work. . Thank you so much!

Comment: Last question bro, what if i want to change the date data delimiter "yyyy-mm-dd" into something like this "yyyy/mm/dd", how can i do it?

Comment: @N.Omugs Change the `strftime("%Y/%m/%d")`.